# Best way to delete/don't load a .php file?

Tags: php, functions

In my theme files, I have a footer.php file that I can delete with no repercussions because I am using something else.

What is the best way to delete/don't load that .php file?

Until now I'm deleting it every updates, but it's starting to be very frustrating to do that every time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're not using it, it's not going to load, so why do you need to delete it? Generally you shouldn't be editing third party themes like this because any changes will be lost on update anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you use a third-party theme, don't your development. The best way, in my opinion, is to make a child theme of the discussed and disable or remove the get_footer() function there.